# Discard all changes at once using GitHub Desktop

Tags: git, github, github-desktop

How can I discard all changes at once in GitHub Desktop? (I use it on Windows)

I used to do:

[image]

but can't see the option any more since GitHub for Windows upgraded itself silently (and changed its name to GitHub Desktop on the way).

I don't want to do it manually for each file one by one. I know I can use the git shell.

I use the latest version of GitHub Desktop, viz. 3.0.1.1.

Comment: What about GitHub Desktop? (https://desktop.github.com/release-notes/windows/ or https://desktop.github.com/release-notes/mac/)

Comment: Oh right, thanks for pointing that out, looks like the program has its name updated when it got upgraded.

Comment: Yes, but do you see that option in the new GitHub Desktop?

Comment: @VonC No, it seems the option moved or disappeared.

Comment: Ok, but 3.0.1.1 sounds ancient. Right now, GitHub Desktop for Windows is at v3.0.3.

Answer (score 62, accepted):

I found it... now we need to right-click precisely on the "X changes" text in blue:

[image]

---

On  GitHub Desktop for Mac v2.17: `Menu Bar > Repository > Discard Changes to Selected Files`.

[image]

---

Related issues:

- [Undo Discard Changes #861](https://github.com/desktop/desktop/issues/861)
- [Allow discarding of individual lines in a file #2402](https://github.com/desktop/desktop/issues/2402)

Comment: I am having similar problem with the new version 0.8.0, I dint find "Discard changes to Selected Files" under Repository

Comment: I believe they have now removed the Discard Changes To Selected Files option from the Repository menu. Terrible.

Answer (score 6):

This ought to be just a comment, but I thought a screenshot of current looks might be useful. So to add to Franck's excellent answer:

[image]